# Ubuntu not getting ipv6 address automatically

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dhcp, ipv6

I'm running Ubuntu Server 18.04 and for some reason it's not getting a global IPv6 address on startup.  It has a link-local (`fe80`) address on `ens18` (ethernet interface), but not a global one.  To get a global one I have to run `sudo dhclient -6 ens18`, but putting that in a crontab with `@reboot` doesn't seem to work either.

The DHCPv6 server is OPNSense (track interface WAN to LAN for prefix, running own DHCPv6 instead of tracking interface)

How can I make it get a global scope IPv6 address on startup?

Comment: How did you configure networking on the computer?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I haven't changed any network settings since the install (where it autoconfigured with dhcp, though I have static leases set in OPNSense for all servers).

Comment: Then what is the current network configuration?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

my /etc/network/interfaces originally had:

```
iface <interface> inet auto
```

I made the changes to the following:

```
iface <interface> inet6 dhcp
```

now my VM boots every time with a ipv6 global address